# обновить фрагмент после изменения в настройках приложения

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

Есть драйвер лайяут с фрагментами и одной активностью, на этой активности всякие настройки.  Запускаем приложение, запускается фрагмент, потом вызываем драйвер лайяут и выбираем активность с настройками, в ней выбираем нужные нам параметры и нажимаем кнопку назад, возвращаемся на фрагмент с которого мы вызывали активность с настройками и фрагмент не обновился, если выбрать через драйвер другой фрагмент, а потом вернуться то изменения будут видны. Вопрос, как обновить фрагмент после возврата на него с активности?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого надо уведомить фрагмент о изменении в настройках и применить их.

1. указываем фрагменту реализовать нужный интерфейс:

   ```
   implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
   ```
2. регистрируем во фрагменте слушатель изменений настроек. Добавьте в `onCreate` фрагмента:

   ```
   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
   ```
3. реализуем интерфейс, определяем какая настройка изменена по её ключу и как-то применяем изменившиеся настройки:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
   {
       Log.i("WOW!", "onSharedPreferenceChanged with key: " + key);
       if (!isAdded())
       {
           return;
       }
       if (key.equals(ТУТ_К_Л_КЛЮЧ_ИЗ_НАСТРОЕК))
       {
          //Вот в этом месте вы можете менять что-то во фрагменте в момент
          //изменения конкретной настройки
          //Если лень менять всё руками можно поступить плохо и просто пересоздать активити: getActivity().recreate();
       }
   }
   ```

---

Ещё вариант - применять настройки в момент отображения фрагмента на экране, т.е. в методе `onResume()`

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    //назначаем, например, цвет текста и настроек
    int btnFontColor = prefs.getInt("key_pref_custom_inter_color_font_button", getResources().getColor(R.color.color_inter_color_font_button));
    btnKnow.setTextColor(btnFontColor);
}
```

Comment: изменения отслеживаются, `getActivity().recreate();` не вариант, сразу при изменение любой нужной мне настройки выкидывает на стартовый фрагмент, а если делать так, то никаких изменений не происходит `if (key.equals("key_pref_custom_inter_color_font_button") {


            btnKnow.setTextColor(btnFontColor);
        }` мне нужно менять цвет текста и фона под ним

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв, поясните `если делать так, то никаких изменений не происходит`. У вас не вызывается обработчик изменений в настройках или не меняется цвет текста? Если второе, то это уже отдельный вопрос. Или он не меняется только в этом обработчике а обычно меняется?

Comment: Не меняется цвет текста, обработчик работает, так как выводятся в лог ключи настроек, которые изменены. По сути мне нужно, что бы по нажатию кнопки назад на активности настроек, я перешел на фрагмент с которого зашел в эту активность и этот фрагмент обновился, то есть поменял цвет элементов, которые я выбрал в настройках.

Comment: А если при создании фрагмента цвет задать, то он меняется?.. Может вы попадаете в `if (!isAdded())`

Comment: ерунду написал)) Смотрите у меня 4 фрагмента, в которых по сути одинаковые элементы будут менять цвет и фон, и вот я возвращаюсь с настроек в фрагмент, изменений нет, перехожу в другой фрагмент там изменения уже есть, возвращаюсь назад в фрагмент и изменения есть.

Comment: думал что будет очень просто в onPause прописать команду обновления фрагмента и все будет работать, а тут такая засада (

Comment: Вы что-то не так делаете... После возврата из настроек должен вызываться onResume. Попробуйте в нём цвет поменять.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33728/discussion-between---and-).